# Ambient light detection - iPhone

Tags: iphone, device

I'd like to use the device's ambient light detection for my app (to set my app luminance in relation to daylight/moonlight). Is it possible? If so, where can i find the API?

Thanks for your future answers.

Answer (score 1):

This [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165539/iphone-proximity-sensor) may be of use - it discusses the proximity sensor, ambient light sensor, and undocumented SDK calls. Looks like there is some sample code too.

Comment: ok, thanks. If i understand well, there's no way to use the ambiant light sensor, isn't it?