# Get the temperature from the iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, hardware, sensors

When you leave your iPhone in your car during summer time, the iPhone my have an overheating issue, then the phone will be locked until the heat back to normal "See the below screenshot".

Then, the iPhone can detect Weather changes, and that led me to this question, is it possible to get the temperature using iPhone's sensors ?

That would make a great weather app that runs offline, and detect the temperature for each place independently.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Temperature Sensor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077324/iphone-temperature-sensor)

Comment: not possible iOS can only detect temperatures using external peripheral devices only.. there is already an example core bluetooth temperature sensor which needs a external device.

Answer (score -3):

**Phone [Overheating issue](https://phoneaxa.com/how-to-fix-overheating-phone-android-iphone/) due to usually two reasons**

- **Phone Battery panel

  CPU & GPU**

**How you can find your Phone overheating due to CPU & GPU or Battery Panel?**

If your phone heat up in camera side or upper side of the phone then it means your phone heat up due to CPU/ GPU but If your phone heat up in lower side then it means your phone heat up due to battery panel.

**How to fix overheating Phone due to Battery Panel?**

If your phone heat up due to battery panel then usually due to these reasons.

Use Fast charger if it’s not compatible with your phone

If you are not use original charger

Charging using phone cover

External Heat:

Charge in wrong Enviromint “charge when your phone put in any hot place
If you put your phone in pocket or in leather bag it's may cause heating issue.
Use phone in high brightness

Don’t overcharge your phone always keep it at 80% to 90% of charged.

Use low quality charging cables.

How to fix overheating Phone due to CPU/GPU?

**If your phone heat up due to CPU/GPU then usually due to these reasons.**

Due to those applications whose running in background and use lot of CPUS.
Phone software issue / software update issue.
Poor signals
Solution

You must uninstall or freeze those application whose running every time in background or must find those applications alternative.
Try to use your phone without back cover if you are in safe place because back cover also causes heating issue of CPU & Battery.
Don’t use your phone when your phone in charging mode.
Close background apps.
Poor signals are also may cause of phone heating because when your phone receives low signals then it tries to supply more power to Antina for better performance.

Note: If your phone temperature is less than 48 c° it considered normal.

Comment: While you included multiple useful facts for iPhone users who are struggling with overheating, it doesn't answer the question that was actually asked.