# How to detect Proximity Sensor?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

how to detect whether the user hear this audio in proximity or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First detect state of Proximity Sensor using [iPhone Proximity Sensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165539/iphone-proximity-sensor)
and then play audio using phone call speaker [Play audio through upper (phone call) speaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026578/play-audio-through-upper-phone-call-speaker)

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setProximityMonitoringEnabled:YES]
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(sensorStateChange:)
    name:@"UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
```