# iOS: Black out screen when putting phone against ear

Tags: ios, feasibility

Is it possible to programmatically replicate the iPhone feature where the screen dims and the touch functionalities are shut off when the phone is against your ear?

Comment: I have certainly seen VOIP app on iOS did it but never tried to implement it myself

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/168561/1040347

Answer (score 3):

```
UIDevice.current.isProximityMonitoringEnabled = true
```

This should enable to proximity sensor and automatically turn screen off when holding against ear